# Image path in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, absolute-path

I have a image path in AngularJs `$scope` variable `imageUrl`, which comes from external source.

http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5579/14671096893_806ec359b7_m.jpg

I am trying to get the image on HTML page.

```
<img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}">
```

But when I am trying to run this in firefox, it is giving me error

```
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost/demo/view/html/%5B%22http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5579/14671096893_806ec359b7_m.jpg%22%5D"
```

Its taking root path of project.
How can I make some changes to show image on the web page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the error that was generated, it contains some url encoded characters as well.  I entered it into [a Url Decoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) and this is what the image url string actually looks like.

```
http://localhost/demo/view/html/["http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5579/14671096893_806ec359b7_m.jpg"]
```

Notice the bracket and quote characters?

This leads me to believe that `$scope.imageUrl` contains the `[""]` symbols. You can easily test this out by rendering the value in a `<pre>` tag next to the `<img>` tag like so...

```
<img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}">
<pre>{{imageUrl}}</pre>
```

If the value in the rendered `<pre>` tag has the `[""]` symbols, then the solution is to remove those symbols from the `$scope.imageUrl` property.

You can remove these symbols from imageUrl like so...

```
$scope.imageUrl = $scope.imageUrl.replace(/[\[\"\]]/g, "");
```

However, if you're using the $http service to retrieve this data from the Flickr API, you should consider using the `transformResponse` option which allows you to manipulate data (in your case, strip out bad characters from the imageUrl) from an http request before resolving the promise.

Comment: Do you know how they are getting there in the first place?

Comment: Its coming from the Flickr API.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example of how you could strip the unwanted characters. - It would be interesting to see the code you're using to retrieve the data from Flickr

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle and it is working perfectly in chrome and firefox. Hope it solves your problem

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvusv/)

HTML Markup:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="test">
        <img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it runs with html. But creating problem with server.

Comment: @Ankit: Seeing your error again you need to remove the localhost url so from http://localhost/demo/view/html/%5B%22http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5579/14671096893_806ec359b7_m.jpg%22%5D" you need to have http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5579/14671096893_806ec359b7_m.jpg%22%5D"

Answer (score 0):

html-

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="test">
    <img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}">
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

js-

```
function test($scope){

     $scope.imageUrl = 'https://angularjs.org/img/AngularJS-small.png';

  }
```